# Azure Storage Emulator via NuGet?

Tags: nuget, azure-storage, nuget-package

Is it possible to get the Azure Storage Emulator using NuGet? If so, where does it get installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Please visit [Azure SDK Downloads page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) to download Azure Storage Emulator.